# MYSQL Queries not working after I changed my timezone in my machine

Tags: java, mysql, date

I am having some strange issues for most of the my queries where I have timestamp and date fields, the queries which were working fine are not working now after I changed the timezone from PST TO IST.

Consider this query,

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from `mydb`.`mytable` WHERE (Date(timestamp) BETWEEN '2013-12-01' and '2012-12-16') and scpets= 'accessories' and images = 'Yes' and videoflag = 'Yes' and maps = 'Yes' and flag = 1 and title LIKE '%Book%' order  by Date(timestamp) desc Limit 0, 100
```

I gives me 0 record back when I know there exists  2 records which meets query criteria.

Now when I remove the between clause from the queries It gives me correct records back.I am lost here as where to make the correction now as query looks perfectly fine and correct inputs are passed from my program to sql queries.All fields marked with Yes are enum columns.

Also My SimpleDataParser class which was working fine till 2 weeks back is now failing with unparseable date exception.I fixed this one,but still my above functionality is broken.

Can someone suggest me is their any relation between the change I did to my laptop(I changed my laptop's timezone from PST TO IST).I have mysql and jdk and all servers on my laptop.

Now I am scared to reverse the change back as it might broke my app completely and I really dont want to do unnecessary rework.

Comment: When you run the query from the mysql client, does it return rows?  I would question your assumptions about the result set.  You should also try SELECT id, Date(timestamp) FROM mytable to check the date results.

Comment: No even with my sql client, it does not give me anything.Let me check date results.

Comment: SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable where Date(timestamp)='2012-12-15' and scpets = 'accessories' and title like '%book%';

Comment: The above queries give me perfect result.I have only 2 records meeting the like criteria.Its only when I add between clause between 2012-12-01 to 2012-12-15 its failing.This is how my timestamp column data looks like,2012-12-15 13:21:45,
2012-12-15 13:36:08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah my bad, I am searching a future dates(**2013-12-01**' and '2012-12-16), my bad in jquery datepicker , I added default date +365 instead of doing -365.Issue is resolved.I really dont know why keep doing silly mistakes and then wasting hours to correct those.

Comment: Silly? A bit like answering your own question instead of updating the original question? :)

Comment: It's ok to answer own questions. You can mark the answer as correct if your question is resolved - or delete the question if it's not going to help anybody else

Comment: Okay, I'll stop being mildly sarcastic then. :)